# awk instead of sed is not working (slow, laggy and wrong output)

Tags: shell, sed, stream, awk, keyboard-events

Why is `awk` not working for the following command instead of `sed`:

```
su -c "stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 od --width=144 -x /dev/input/event3 | sed 's%^\([a-z0-9]\+ \)\{11\}%%;s%\(....\).*%\1%'"
```

This prints at every keypress the **USB HID ID number of the key that was pressed**.

Example output (`0028` is for <kbd>Return</kbd> and `00e4` for <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd>):

```
0028
0028
0028
0028
0028
00e4
00e4
00e4
```

This are two lines of output **without** `sed`/`cut`/`awk` filtering when pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> two times. The USB HID ID number is in column 12:

```
0000000 2d6f 511e 0000 0000 051b 0007 0000 0000 0004 0004 0028 0007 2d6f 511e 0000 0000 051d 0007 0000 0000 0001 001c 0000 0000 2d6f 511e 0000 0000 051e 0007 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 2d73 511e 0000 0000 a150 0007 0000 0000 0004 0004 0028 0007 2d73 511e 0000 0000 a153 0007 0000 0000 0001 001c 0001 0000 2d73 511e 0000 0000 a154 0007 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000220 2d73 511e 0000 0000 9b5a 0008 0000 0000 0004 0004 0028 0007 2d73 511e 0000 0000 9b5d 0008 0000 0000 0001 001c 0000 0000 2d73 511e 0000 0000 9b5e 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 2d74 511e 0000 0000 4f90 0005 0000 0000 0004 0004 0028 0007 2d74 511e 0000 0000 4f93 0005 0000 0000 0001 001c 0001 0000 2d74 511e 0000 0000 4f94 0005 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I tried it with

```
su -c "stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 od --width=144 -x /dev/input/event3 | cut -d' ' -f12"
```

and it also works. But it only shows the keys pressed **after the next two keypresses**. stdbuf did not help here, although it should adjusts standard input/output/error stream buffering to 0.

My `mawk` command looked like this:

```
su -c "stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 od --width=$((48*3)) -x /dev/input/event3 | mawk '{ print $12 }'"
```

but it only showed me some twos and then some newlines and again twos. It seems very laggy/slow. When I press a key, nothing happens. After **pressing different keys** multiple times, **I always get** a bunch of twos and newlines. **No matter which keys** I pressed! Example:

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2












2
2
```

How can I fix this? Why is this occurring?

### Update

When I use `gawk` instead of `mawk` it does not lag any more (unbuffered). But I still don’t see the correct values which should be `0028` or `00e4` and so on for <kbd>Return</kbd> and <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd> as example keys.

Comment: try adding '-u' to awk invocation, to have it unbuffer the output.

Comment: I have mawk 1.3.3 on this system and it tells me `awk: not an option: -u`

Comment: I installed gawk. It does not have an option `-u` either, but the output seems unbuffered. So, my last problem is: Why is it only showing twos (2)?

Comment: have you tried using ``dd`` ?

Comment: @sotapme What do you mean? Instead of what? Reading the event device with dd and piping it to od?

Comment: I thought that ``dd`` had better control of it's buffering and yes I'd pipe it through ``od`` - I'm on ``osx`` so we don't have ``stdbuf``. In that you want to see it coming into ``od`` as soon as you hit a key.

Comment: I tried it with `dd if=/dev/input/event3 | od` but it was even worse. Maybe because stdbuf now only works on dd and not on od. … Ok, now I tried it with both unbuffering dd and od. Still laggy. It was better without dd. And I still get only *twos* as result. As I wrote in the update: The lag problem is gone when using gawk instead of mawk.

Comment: Debug it by adding a for loop to print every field within delimiters, e.g. `{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print NR,NF,i,"<"$i">"; print "----" }`

Comment: @Ed Morton Thank you for that idea. That finally helped me. I will answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the comments I came to the solution.

@Olivier Dulac brought me to the idea that there are different `awk` implementations, which solved the problem of the laggyness (using `gawk` instead of `mawk`). I don’t even need the `stdbuf`.

@Ed Morton’s idea brought me to a problem, because he used quotes `"` in his example. I already had quotes in my statement around the whole thing, because it was executed using `su`. So I had to escape them.

My whole statement looks like this (notice the escaped dollar sign in front of the 12):

```
su -c "od --width=144 -x /dev/input/event3 | awk '{ print \$12 }'"
```

and now it works as expected.

Comment: If you'd told us initially about the script being inside su -c quotes I expect you'd have got an immediate response telling you what the problem was instead of several people wasting their time trying to figure it out from the command line you said you were using.

Comment: Sorry about that. I’ve learned that and will post the whole command in the future.